# Gathering a full year of question data from the API

Tags: discussion, api

I want to try doing a data analysis project based on a large amount of SO question data. Specifically, I want to take a year worth of question data (from 2018/01/01 to 2019/01/01), and look for certain trends.

I looked at the question API and realized I could do something like [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=2018-01-01&todate=2019-01-01&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) which gives me all the data points I need.

The problem is, I don't think I'm allowed to pull this much data this way in any reasonable amount of time. Looking over the [throttling page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), I'm limited to 10,000 requests a day, which is problematic when combined with the fact that page sizes max out at 100.

If I go to the 20,000th page, that only takes me back to like September. That means I'd have to max out my daily requests for 3 days to gather the data.

Is there a better way of going about this, and/or is gathering this much data considered abusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Exchange Data Dump allows you to download *all* the data locally so you can query it as much as you like.

You can read more about that here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/350567)

Comment: I missed that data could be exported from SEDEs. That'll work actually. Thanks.